# jquery dropdown toggle table row

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a dropdown toogle for a table. The main purpose is when a main row is clicked then its sub rows has to disappear.

The problem is when i insert a variable into the selector it is not working.

here is a similar table:

```
     <table border="1">    
         <thead>
            <tr class="btn-info">
              <th>header</th>
              <th>header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tr id="main1" class="bg-primary">
              <td>maintext1</td>
              <td>maintext1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr name="toggletext1" class="bg-info">
              <td>subtext1</td>
              <td>subtext1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr name="toggletext1" class="bg-info">
              <td>subtext1</td>
              <td>subtext1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="main2" class="bg-primary">
              <td>maintext2</td>
              <td>maintext2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr name="toggletext2" class="bg-info">
              <td>subtext2</td>
              <td>subtext2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr name="toggletext2" class="bg-info">
              <td>subtext2</td>
              <td>subtext2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and the script:

```
<script>        
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            for (x=1;x<=500;x++){
                $('#main'+x).on('click', function() {
                    $("tr[name=toggletext"+x+"]").slideToggle();    
                });
            }
        });     
        </script>
```

if i change the script like:

```
$("tr[name=toggletext1]").slideToggle();
```

then it is working but obviously only the rows with the name of "toggletext1" will toggle. even if i click on the main with id=2;

any help would be appropriated

Comment: You just want to toggle some rows on other rows click right?

Comment: yes. example u click on main1 row then all the toggletext1 rows have to appear and disappear.

Comment: as i mentioned it works fine if i use $("tr[name=toggletext1]").slideToggle(); but when i change toggletext1 to  $("tr[name=toggletext"+x+"]").slideToggle(); then not working. but i need to use variable cos there will be a lot of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bg-primary').on('click', function() {
    $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).slideToggle();
  }).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="btn-info">
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr id="main1" class="bg-primary">
    <td>maintext1</td>
    <td>maintext1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-info main1 hide">
    <td>subtext1</td>
    <td>subtext1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-info main1 hide">
    <td>subtext1</td>
    <td>subtext1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="main2" class="bg-primary">
    <td>maintext2</td>
    <td>maintext2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr name="toggletext2" class="bg-info main2 hide">
    <td>subtext2</td>
    <td>subtext2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr name="" class="bg-info main2 hide">
    <td>subtext2</td>
    <td>subtext2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi. tanks. it works however i had to get rid of the hide from the class otherwise it did nothing. <tr class="bg-info main2"> instead of <tr class="bg-info main2 hide"> still this is simplier than mine so thanx again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

ok. sorry. my mistake. the for loop here is useless. i do not even know why i used that.
i need to change the whole structure here. so when i click on  a main row then i need to get the number of its id (or maybe i will use only numbers for id)
and all the subrows with the name of toggletext + the id number need to toggle.

my mistake. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i made it work.

```
<script>        
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            //when a tr is clicked
            $("tr").on('click', function() {
                //get the id of the tr                  
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                //toggle the subrows with the name + id
                $("tr[name=toggletext"+id+"]").slideToggle();   
            });
        }); 
        </script>
```

i changed the name of the id's(main1, main2) to (1,2,...)